# Does MgCl2 sol coagulate gold sol faster than Fe(OH)3 sol?

Tags: physical-chemistry, colloids

Here is a question from the former [AIEEE 2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Entrance_Examination_%E2%80%93_Main)

> The disperse phase in colloidal iron (III) hydroxide and colloidal gold is positively and negatively charged respectively. Which of the following statements is not correct?
>
> (a) Mixing the sols has no effect
>
> (b) Coagulation in both sols can be brought about by electrophoresis.
>
> (c) Magnesium chloride solution coagulates the gold sol. more readily than the iron (III) hydroxide sol.
>
> (d) Sodium sulphate solution causes coagulation in both sols.

It is a single answer correct, and it is obvious that **(a)** is false - hence is the answer. But the statement **(c)** also seems to be false (and therefore should also be an answer).

According to Hardy Schulze law,

> Greater the valency of the flocculating ion, greater will be its coagulation power.

Doesn't that mean $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$ sol, having $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ ions, will coagulate the gold sol more readily than $\ce{MgCl2}$ sol, which contains $\ce{Mg^{2+}}$ ions? Or is there any specific reason why the $\ce{MgCl2}$ sol coagulates the gold sol more readily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option (c) is actually correct. Magnesium chloride does coagulate gold sol faster than ferric hydroxide, because ferric hydroxide does not coagulate in the first place.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(III)_oxide-hydroxide) mentions that ferric hydroxide is insoluble at $\ce{pH}=7$, so there aren't any $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ ions to coagulate the gold sol anyway.